# Reload single jqGrid row?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, reload

How can you reload a SINGLE jqGrid row?

We know how to reload the entire grid - but we just want to update a single row when we know that the data in the row has changed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you hold the data on the server and your server support filtering of data ([single](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching) of [advance searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching)) then you can use the same url which you use in jqGrid for your manual `jQuery.ajax` calling. You should set only the filter to `id` equal to the row which you need to refresh. On successful response from the server you can use `setRowData` or `delRowData` to update the row contain or to delete the row.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update the tr id as well, otherwise it will save it multiple times on next edit.

```
function afterSave(p,p2) { 
    $('#mygrid').setRowData(lastSel,{'id':newId});
    $('#'+lastSel).attr("id",newId);
}
```