# Update and Reload Single Row in jqgrid

Tags: php, javascript, jqgrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reload single jqGrid row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786445/reload-single-jqgrid-row)

I have a jqGrid and I used ondblClickRow event to show the edit dialog. I know how to reload the whole grid but I want to reload only the row the one that I ondblClickRow after I click the Close button in my Edit Dialog it will automatically view my updated data in my grid. Can some one give me an idea or Sample Code(must very appreciated) how to do this.

P.S. I know that there is the same question that already raise about this topic but I still dont get the idea how to do this. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: @Dragon: Yes I already searched that. but can you give me a sample code? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this post and the last answer

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/reload-row/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried that but still not working. Do you have other idea how to reload Singe row after I close the dialog? Thanks in advance.

Comment: buddy even i'm at my work so dont expect me to write code for u. I can give u idea about it.in ur OnClickSubmit event in ur edit options get the data of the row u want to update. If u have the Id you can get the data with getCell or getRowData. Now stringyfy this data and send it as json with an ajax(jquery) request to controller.In the success function of ajax request, use setRowData and update ur row with data you were sending to controller.u are doing this in success parameter,so u can be pretty sure that record has been updated in database and u can setRowData with the data u were sending.